# How can I clone a bioentry record in a BioSQL database

Tags: python, biopython

I need to completely clone a record from one sub database to another. I don't seem to be able to plug lookup into load directly, and whilst I could write to a file and read it back in again that seems to be a rather inelegant solution.

A side-but-central question to this is: is there a simple way to completely load a DBSeqRecord into a conventional SeqRecord?

Many thanks!

Comment: can you show us some code of what you have tried so far?